# Is the Pro Tools Field Recorder Track feature only available in HD versions?

Tags: field-recording, pro-tools

According to [Avid's site](http://www.avid.com/US/products/Pro-Tools-Software-comparison-table), the regular version of PT 11 has Field Recorder capabilities.

[image]

However, when I right click my audio tracks, all I see is this tiny menu:

[image]

Is this a pro feature or not? I am perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

Today, received this answer from AVID:

Entered By : Dan Spier
Entered on : 14/04/2015 17:23
Hi Balthasar

I have checked with our engineering team and as I thought, this is a Pro Tools HD only feature. 
It is not available with Pro Tools 12.

I am now working with the web team to remove this from the Pro Tools 12 column. 
Thank you for bringing this to our attention, please let me know if you need further assistance.

Regards, 
D Spier 
Avid Audio Support

no comment....